# How can I create online meetings/events for non Azure AD users?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

Essentially what I want is a website where the user doesn't have to be an member of my Azure AD, just wants access to a new online meeting/event. I also need to be able to create an online meeting or event link on behalf of my application (NOT the user)

I have set up a registered app on Azure that has the following permissions for the application:
[image]

Am I able to create an online meeting/event for this application or does it HAVE to be on a users behalf?

I know I have to use the following:

```
graphServiceClient.Users["{user id/upn}"].OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

If it is possible to create on behalf of the application, then what would the user email be? - admin email?

Any help on understanding this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an online meeting using Application permission with Microsoft Graph Beta version: [Create onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

V1.0 version doesn't support Application permission.

Please note that Application permission also creates the online meeting on behalf a user because the user ID specified in the request path is necessary.

Based on the **Important** tip [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions), you also must [create an application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) to allow applications to access online meetings on behalf of a user.

The user email id should be configured in the policy `Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy`.

Comment: Thanks so much for that, it is the access policy! There are a few further questions this raises for me tho: It would seem I have to run the command for each newly created Azure AD account (which I hope can be done in .NET on creation) and it doesn't seem to work for guest users. Do you know anything around these further issues?

Comment: @mattsharp  Yes. you need to run the command for each account. I'm not sure if it works for guest users. Maybe it's related to O365 Teams license?

Comment: Yeah I don't think it does work for guest users and running the command for each user is not what i have in mind :(. I've gone with events (create them as online meetings) which does what i need to do. Thanks for the response!